# How to publish web project to specific local folder via TeamBuild and MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, web, local, publish, tfsbuild

I was searching quiet a lot around to get this problem solved - but couldn't find an appropriate solution.
I have a C# .NET solution with around 16 projects in it and want it to be built nightly via TeamBuild and MSBuild.
Two of the projects are web projects that shouuld be published after building the solution or project - but the problem is: it should be compiled in its normal output path, and published to a specific folder on the local file system. In Visual Studio this is no problem - I click publish on local file system and the project is published fine.

I already found some MSbuild Options like DelpoyOnBuild and so on, but all the examples only work for a publish on IIS WebServer - but I don't want to use IIS in this case. Is it possible to make MSBuild publish/deploy the web project to a specified local folder after Build?

Best regards
Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you will have to adapt your process template a bit. A separate process could handle the publishing part, using the files in the drop folder a base. Then you can use whatever tool you like, with the `InvokeProcess` activity, or develop your own custom activity that handles it.

Whether this process is part of the standard build process or in a separate template/build definition is up to how you wish to have it executed.

We use [Community TFS Build Extensions](http://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/), and with those extra activities we can use `InvokeBuild` to start other builds, for example at the end of another. By passing along the current build Uri and then use their `GetBuildDetail`, any build can know its predecessor and have access to all its details (like `DropFolder`, for instance).

Answer (score 0):

I did this now with a post build event or with a simple command file, that invokes msbuild.exe. msbuild is startet with parameters, so that it deploys the web service. This is my command:

```
MSBuild.exe /target:Build;PipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder /p:Configuration=Release;_PackageTempDir=%binfolder% "projectfile.csproj"
```